# OpenLDAP uidNumber assignation

Tags: openldap

I am new to LDAP.

I am creating items from the posixAccount ObjectClass, which requires **uidNumber** ( must attribute ).

How can/should I assign that number to that item? Is there a guideline about it or is it just a random number?

I went to ldapwiki but didn't find much relevant information there.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's up to you to assign the uidNumber in the way that works best for your deployment.

You should choose a range that is not going to overlap with any locally-defined users on the systems. For example local users often have ids starting with 1000. I like to start my LDAP uids at 10000.

You should also ensure that you don't assign the same uidNumbers to two different users. The [slapo-unique(5)](https://openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapo-unique&apropos=0&sektion=5&manpath=OpenLDAP+2.4-Release&arch=default&format=html) overlay can help with that. I like to use a `sambaUnixIdPool` object to track my uid and gid allocations. (`sambaUnixIdPool` is defined in `samba.schema` and you don't have to be using Samba.)